# c# get microphone volume and set a specific value as event

Tags: c#, audio, volume, microphone

I want to read out the volume of the sound the microphone currently records.
I need this value to trigger an event as soon as the volume gets higher than a specific amount and trigger another event as soon as it falls back down this amount.

Currently I am using Istrib.Sound and Istrib.Sound.Mp3, but i have no idea if this works with those dll files. I am using these to record the input (I got everything open source so that could be why I don't understand the depths of Istrib) but its with normalized volume. And if i turn off normalizeVolume I just can't get the current volume out.

Is there a possibility to do this with standard libraries? Or has anyone an example of how to easily read out the volume?

Comment: I've used nAudio in the past. It's a solid audio library for .NET. This sample may get you started in the right direction: http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/NET-Voice-Recorder

Comment: Nice lib. I think with this tutorial I'll get what I want. Thank you